# JavaScript precent multiple keypress action

Tags: javascript

I made a simple snake game. It works like a charm but there is a bug with multiple keypressing.

For example, when you are going to top direction and press left and down or right and down at the same time, the snake just simply dies on the same line.

So here is the code for the keypress

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);

function keyDown(event){
    //up
    if(event.keyCode == 38){
        if(yVelocity == 1)
            return;
        yVelocity = -1;
        xVelocity = 0;
    }

    //down
    if(event.keyCode == 40){
        if(yVelocity == -1)
            return;
        yVelocity = 1;
        xVelocity = 0;
    }

    //left
    if(event.keyCode == 37){
        if(xVelocity == 1)
            return;
        yVelocity = 0;
        xVelocity = -1;
    }

     //right
     if(event.keyCode == 39){
        if(xVelocity == -1)
        return;
        yVelocity = 0;
        xVelocity = 1;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to prevent multiple keypressing or any other way to prevent this?

Comment: I've removed the link to your game, as linking to external sites like that is pretty close to spam. If you have the *source code* for the game to help give context to your code, feel free to link to that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the direction changes twice before the snake's shape is updated, and so the first of those two direction changes is actually ignored.

A way to overcome this, is to buffer the direction changes in a queue (implemented as array).

So in your key event handler you would not do this:

```
if (snake.direction != 1)  
    snake.direction = 3;
```

But instead:

```
if ((snake.queue.length ? snake.queue[0] : snake.direction) != 1) 
    snake.queue.unshift(3);
```

This queue should be initialised in the `Snake` constructor:

```
this.queue = [];
```

Then when you update the snake's position (at a time interval), you would *consume* that queue if there is something in it:

```
if (snake.queue.length)
    snake.direction = snake.queue.pop();
// Now apply this direction:
//   ... this would be code you already have...
```

You could set a maximum to this queue size, as it can get awkward if the user keeps pressing keys faster than the snake updates.